# Is it possible that two miners mine blocks with different headers because they include different transactions

Tags: transactions, mining-theory

Ok, it's a yes or no question: miners can include different transactions in a block, so does that mean that they search for different nonces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, different miners will almost certainly always search for different nonces. Besides including different transactions from the network, they will also almost certainly send the proceeds from the coinbase transaction to different accounts. There are many other places where the block can also be different.

Comment: In fact at current difficulty the algorithm isn't, as often presented in ancient tutorials, 'search for a nonce that makes an otherwise-fixed block valid' but rather 'search for a block (by varying _at least_ coinbase) for which there exists _any_ nonce that makes it valid'.